# Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, notify

I'm trying to push a notification if socket gets received.

Server side:

```
if(data.handle.length > 0 && data.message.length > 0){
  io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
} else {
  socket.emit('error');
}
```

Client side:

```
socket.on('error', function(){
  $.amaran({
      'theme'     :'colorful',
      'content'   :{
         bgcolor:'red',
         color:'#fff',
         message:'Please enter your name, and message and try again.'
      },
      'position'  :'top right',
      'outEffect' :'slideBottom'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `error` event is "reserved" for internal use by SocketIO, so you shouldn't use it for any of your own events. Use something like `data-error` instead:

```
socket.emit('data-error');

socket.on('data-error', ...);
```